# vpp-core in a build asks for symlinks which breaks build

Tags: yocto, bitbake

I am trying to build for a Layerscape platform, but am getting an error on vpp-core.

I have been trying to figure out what isn't right. The files exist but they are not symlinks. They are binaries.  Is there a simple fix? Such as a verb change in the .bb file?

Here's two of the several errors..

> ERROR: vpp-core-19.01-r0 do_package_qa: QA Issue: -dev package contains non-symlink .so: vpp-core-dev path '/work/aarch64-fsl-linux/vpp-core/19.01-r0/packages-split/vpp-core-dev/usr/lib/vpp_plugins/avf_plugin.so'

> -dev package contains non-symlink .so: vpp-core-dev path '/work/aarch64-fsl-linux/vpp-core/19.01-r0/packages-split/vpp-core-dev/usr/lib/vpp_plugins/nat_plu**gin.so'

The binaries exist.  What baffles me is why is it looking for a symlinks?

The bitbake file is `vpp-core.bb`.

Comment: Removed all references in the yocto recipes to vpp-core.  It seems to be unsupported.